# Unable to get back Windows 7 partition entry in Grub2 Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I had Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my system along with Windows 7, running perfectly. Then I upgraded to 14.04 and many things in many things went wrong so I decided to format just my Ubuntu partition (deleted it and set it as root `/`) and install 12.04 once again, on that partition. This time, the grub disappeared. I tried `grub-update`, I got it back but without the Windows partition, even though it does exist.

I ran `boot-repair` disk, it said everything went fine, but still not getting my Windows partition entry in grub yet.

Here is a [LINK](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8435188/) of the execution trace from boot-repair. It says in the end that `/mnt/boot-sav/sda3/` may need repair, which is the partition of Windows.

I already tried to run a repair with Windows bootable disk but it says that the automatic repair can't be performed.

I'm still not getting what needs to be done.

How to solve it ?

Comment: You converted your (hidden in Windows) sda2 boot partition into swap. A Windows repair will look at the partition with the boot flag and try to repair it. Since swap is not NTFS, of course it cannot fix it. Use gparted and move boot flag to sda3. You do not have to have the Boot partition with Windows, but Windows repairs have to add bootmgr and BCD files for it to boot.

Comment: Welcome to AU! Do I understand you correctly, that there is no Grub menu at all during boot? Everybody else seems to assume the Windows entry in the Grub menu vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the package os-prober installed?
If not, try to download it and run grub-update once again.
Hope it helps.

Raphael

Comment: I have it already installed, I upgraded it, and ran grub update once again. Still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: And what happens if you mount your windows partition? Is it readable on Ubuntu? Just to know if the partition is corrupted or if it is simply not detected.